# I would order my search according some field

Tags: solr

I would order my search according some field. 
For example:
    - title
    - description
    - some field

I would order by title and description. I try QF but this not work in all cases because search only in the specified field. I would to specify a list of field but i don't want exclude other field

Comment: qf is for query fields, not for sorting by fields

Comment: ! What should i do ?

Comment: `sort=somefield`? What do you mean "order my search according some field" otherwise? Do you have any examples?

Comment: I have badly explained. I want sort by SCORE deciding the weight of the files

Answer (score 0):

Sort by score is the default sort if you don't specify anything. Perhaps you are looking to boost matches against specific field. This can be done using eDisMax and specifying boosts in the list of fields.

For example **fl=title^10 description^3 otherfield1 otherfield2**